# A common pattern involving composition of functions (\a b -> f (g a) (g b))

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, declarative, pointfree

The composition of f and g that looks like

```
f :. g = \a b -> f (g a) (g b)
```

is a pattern I find very often in my code. It is similar to unary function composition, only `f` is binary and I want `g` applied to both arguments before they are passed to `f`.

When I ask lambdabot to convert this to point-free form, I get the weird incantation

```
flip ((.) . f . g) g
```

which I'd rather not have in my code, so I end up just writing out the pattern explicitly.

**Is there a commonly accepted way of writing a combinator for this situation?** Or am I weird for finding myself in this situation quite a lot?

I don't have an actual example of when I use this on hand right now since I have never thought to ask here when I've needed it, but one could imagine writing the euclidean distance formula very neatly with it, like so:

```
distance = sqrt . (+) :. (^2)
```

Comment: `flip` could be eliminated: `(. g) . f . g`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This function is called `on` in the `Data.Function` module.

It's often used infix, such as `` sqrt . (+) `on` (^2) ``.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: A common example of use is `sortBy (compare \`on\` abs)`

Comment: I'll note for future Google people however that `comparing abs` is more idiomatic than ``compare `on` abs``. This works because `comparing = on compare` is defined somewhere in the standard libraries.